# Visual Studio 2008 not rendering right on window resize

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, resize

Visual Studio 2008 is not rendering right on window resize or maximize.
This happens a lot -- **does anyone know how to fix it?** It's  very annoying.
(Note I blurred the code, that's usually fine, but the code pane keeps the previous size while the rest of the window resizes.
Also, SSMS does the same thing and I know they are build on the same technology.

[image: visual studio 2008 wtf mate]

EDIT: I'm on Windows 7 x64 Professional. 
Visual Studio 2008 Professional with resharper 5.
Doing some googling, it seems the problem might be related to an nVidia graphics driver.
That doesn't really make sense to me though, it's just 2D standard winforms isn't it?

Comment: For a second, I was like WTF did VS do to your code?

Comment: Odd, for me every version of VS has been fine, but SSMS 2008 R2 does this.  For the latter the only workaround I've come up with is to maximize the app before opening any tabs - it seems to be okay resizing up to its starting size.

Comment: Weird bug; I've never seen this before in any version of Visual Studio. Can you give us any more information about your setup or environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Visual Studio do use the graphics card for rendering, and the Aero theme (which you have enabled) uses it as well.

I suspect two possibilities: either a buggy combination of extensions or a combination of extension and buggy graphics card driver.  If this does not happen in any other applications using the Visual Studio shell (i.e. Sql Server Studio), I would try disabling your extensions, starting with ReSharper.  I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of ReSharper.

As a workaround, you can resize the window by dragging it to full screen.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me, and it was driving me crazy.  I solved it by just dissabling aero from the tool bar

> (Right click on the tool bar -> properties -> uncheck use Aero Peek to
>   preview the desktop)

and all seems fine now, i hope for a long long time.